# Intellisense with PhaserJS Library in Visual Studio Code

Tags: javascript, phaser

I am trying to use Visual Studio code along with PhaserJS but am confused about why the  isn't working.

I've read through http://www.johnpapa.net/intellisense-witha-visual-studio-code/ am think I am doing it correctly but still don't get auto-complete.  When Phaser gets a green underline and lightbulb, the bulb doesn't include a create reference so I created one above manually.

[image: phaser_issue]

Comment: Have you figured it out? I also don't have autocomplete in VS Code

Comment: I tried manually adding a reference path to the phaser.js file and it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try pointing Visual Studio Code to the TypeScript definition:

`/// <reference path="../../../phaser/typescript/phaser.d.ts" />`

You will likely have to correct the path, of course. That got rid of the green underline for me, and now tab completion and CTRL+SPACE works.

Comment: Thanks!  This worked for me.  I went to github and downloaded the phaser.d.ts file, then placed it in my /typings/ directory of my app.